# Selenium web driver native functions work but same functions of ActionChains class do not on the same element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

While trying to automate using Selenium webdriver and python I am facing the following issue:

Simple click is working without action chains class:

`element.click()`

But trying to click is not working using action chains class:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

action = ActionChains(driver)

action.click(element).perform()
```

Similarly, trying to drag drop not working using action chains class:

```
action.drag_and_drop_by_offset(element,0,100).perform()

action.drag_and_drop(element,element2).perform()
```

Using ActionChains gives a stale element exception.

Is there any other way to perform these operations like move_to, mouse_press, mouse_release, drag_drop etc. **without ActionChains class**

Further - working directly with `driver` commands:

```
from selenium.webdriver.remote.command import Command

driver.execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT, {"id":getattr(element,"id")})
```

But this does not:

```
from selenium.webdriver.remote.command import Command

driver.execute(Command.MOVE_TO, {"id":getattr(element,"id")})

driver.execute(Command.MOUSE_DOWN, {})

driver.execute(Command.MOVE_TO, {"id":getattr(element2,"id")})

driver.execute(Command.MOUSE_UP, {})
```

Also, observed that the jquery to retrieve the position of the object returns undefined even though the object is present:

`$($x('div[draggable="true" and @class="result selected-row"][1]')).position()`

Any suggestions?